# how to change the console tty after booting?

Tags: linux, tty, console

the command `dmesg | grep console` returns:

```
Kernel command line: console=ttys6,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 
rootwait rw
console [ttys6] enabled
```

I want to change this to ttys3 after booting. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

The man page for [tty_ioctl](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl) lists the ioctl 
TIOCCONS. When applied to an open file descriptor of a tty it will redirect future output intended for `/dev/console` to that tty.

You can use this in a simple perl script. Create and `chmod +x` a file mysetconsole holding the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397790/119298
# see man tty_ioctl for TIOCCONS
# and perldoc IO::Tty::Constant
require "sys/ioctl.ph";
use IO::Tty::Constant qw(TIOCCONS);
ioctl(STDIN,TIOCCONS,0) or die $!;
```

Assuming you can open the wanted device, use it simply as

```
sudo ./mysetconsole </dev/ttys3
```

You will not be able to use it again until you set the console back to `/dev/console`, with

```
sudo sh -c './mysetconsole </dev/console'
```

You may get perl warnings about `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` which can be ignored.
You will need rpm package `perl-IO-Tty` or debian package `libio-pty-perl`. If you prefer you can just look for the definition of TIOCCONS in the system include files. I found mine in:

```
/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h: #define TIOCCONS      0x541D
```

Your perl script can then just be

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397790/119298
sub TIOCCONS{ return 0x541D; }
ioctl(STDIN,TIOCCONS(),0) or die $!;
```

Comment: This would be a great answer if it included a shell command to call that ioctl.  I could have sworn `dmesg` could do this way back when, but the man page now says otherwise.  I know there was some command I used to use to make an Xterm the console way back when, but can't remember it for the life of me.

Comment: @psusi I added a perl script. `xterm -C` will become console, but you need to be root these days, and it doesn't fit the questioners requirements.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it involved a -c... would make more sense if it was `dmesg` that did this rather than `xterm` though.

Answer (score 1):

For ease of use, many Linux systems provide `setconsole(8)`, that does the same underlying operations as the Perl snippets.

Checking the return is important, it might fail.

```
$ setconsole /dev/ttyS1 ; echo $?
0
```

Proof of the internals:

```
$ strace -ff setconsole /dev/ttyS1
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttyS1", O_WRONLY|O_NOCTTY) = 3
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCCONS)                      = 0
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Short anwser: use chvt
Long anwser: How Linux configures the TTYs at boot depends on distribution. It could be /etc/inittab or it could be /etc/rc.local
On systemd systems it's automatic based on configurations in logind.conf