# Is there a way to change where systemd sends its output during shutdown?

Tags: linux, systemd, console, serial-port, serial-console

I want systemd to send shutdown messages to a TTY that is different from the one that was used during bootup. More specifically, if the system starts to shutdown, the system should send any messages to `/dev/ttyS0`.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. **Get systemd to change where it sends it's output:** `systemd` itself accepts `--default-standard-output`/`--default-standard-error` but I'm unable to find a way to change these settings once systemd has started. `systemctl daemon-rexec` doesn't accept new arguments for the new systemd instance.
2. **Changing the console by setting `TIOCCONS` on `/dev/ttyS0` as described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397700/how-to-change-the-console-tty-after-booting)**: The syscall appears to be successful, but systemd continues to send output to tty1. I suspect this itctl command only redirects the output of the console rather than switch the console's tty (see #3 and #4).
3. **Closing all virtual terminals other than S0 to somehow force systemd to switch to the serial terminal**: This fails because `deallocvt` thinks that tty1 is the console (even after setting `TIOCCONS` on `/dev/ttyS0`). Stopping each virtual terminal's systemd getty service didn't seem to help either.
4. **Naively removing `/dev/tty{1..}` devices using rm, killing associated agetty processes, and ensuring that systemd getty services are stopped**: Still didn't work, perhaps systemd retains an open file descriptor for tty1.

All these attempts failed to stop systemd from using `/dev/tty1` to output shutdown messages. As a last ditch effort, I'm considering [gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process) to edit systemd, but I'd rather avoid going down this route if at all posible.

Is there a way to change where systemd sends its output during shutdown?